# join query with like considering as string

Tags: mysql

```
select a.mac_id, a.expiry_date
from license_info a
join renewal b
on a.mac_id like '%b.desktop%' or a.mac_id like '%b.server%'
```

But %b.desktop% and %b.server% is considering as string. So please help me to solved this kind of scenario.

```
company_name | macid          |  expiry_date
---------------------------------------------
abc          |  123456789012  |  2017-03-23
qwe          |  987654321012  |  2018-05-24
asd          |  456789123012  |  2019-07-07
abc          |  789456123000  |  2017-03-23
abc          |  445544444444  |  2018-03-03
abc          |  555555555555  |  2017-03-25


company_name | desktop         | server 
abc            123456789012      555555555555
               789456123000
```

Comment: if you put stuff into single quotes it becomes a string. The solution is to not quote it. But if scaisEdge's answer does not solve your problem you should really edit the question and try to be more clear. Remebber that we cannot read your mind!

Answer (score 1):

If your query is inside some string
then you can use concat  to avoid that the content is considered a string, preventing the use of wildchar

```
select a.mac_id, a.expiry_date
from license_info a
join renewal b
on a.mac_id like concat('%', b.desktop, '%' )  
    or a.mac_id like concat('%', b.server.'%')
```

Comment: what to do if b.server value are multiple in shell and it is separated with new line \n

Comment: I don't understand you comment .. please update your question and add a proper data sample and the expected  result